lower bound of $\sum \cos^k(\theta_i-\theta_j)$
In this question, Lower bound of sum of cosine of angle difference, the lower bound $\sum_{i,j\in [n]}\cos^2(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq \frac{n^2}{2}$ is given in the answer.
I am wondering, what is the lower bound of $$\sum_{i,j\in [n]}\cos^k(\theta_i-\theta_j)$$
for a fixed integer $k$ , where $k\geq 3$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]^n$?
I took an experiement by random sampling points $\theta\in[0,2\pi]^n$ and it shows that the lower bound is also increasing as $n$ grows. But I don't know how to obtain its explicit lower bound.
Many thanks in advance for any idea!

I think you want $k$ even here as for $k$ odd you can get the sum to be zero for even $n$ by choosing half the angles $0$ and half $\pi$; it is an interesting question for even $k$ though I would say that the lower bound should be (for large $k$) something like $n^2/\sqrt {\pi k}+o(n^2)$

@Conrad  could you briefly mention about how do you think of the case of n being even? why it would be something like $n^2/\sqrt{\pi k}+o(n^2)$? Thank you!

@Conrad ah, I got the result as well. This should be lower bound which cannot be attained by any $\theta$. Seems an exact lower bound is interesting but difficult problem

The result follows from the formula for the even cosine powers in terms of cosine of multiple angles and the asymptotic of the leading term - I agree that a finer result may be trickier but it depends what you want it for as by itself I think the above is fairly satisfactory as these things go but if you need it for a subtler problem better results may be achievable
